Soft Keyboard position Jetpack compose for tv
SO i have a project in which i am using jetpack compose. I'm making a login screen on which i have 2 parts of screen on one part i have username password fields and on the other part i want to show the soft keyboard i have not seen any app using or opening keyboard like this i wasn't able to find any solution for this. how do you manage the position of keyboard is there any way to do this is this possible.


EDIT: For a Jetpack Compose way, Compose team has added support for this in 1.6.0. Related PR for this can be found here
And the Google Bug Tracker can be found here
I'm not sure of a Jetpack Compose solution, but, the EditText in XML can work with something close to what you're expecting using the Floating Mode of Gboard
Gboard ships by default in the Android TV OS and unless an OEM has changed that, you can use privateImeAlignment of the EditText field
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:privateImeOptions="horizontalAlignment=right"> // left or center is also allowed

You can read in detail here

i'm using only jetpack compose. is there any way to make it possible.

Is this what you expected, atleast? Doesn't matter if it's XML or not

Also try checking the linked Jetpack Compose issue, and report back. I can help you on that
